# Looking for a good book on how to code more efficiently in .net c#

Tags: c#

Most C# developers developers, like me have a good solid grasp on the .net framework and the C# language. But I've yet to come across a book that can take a very good c# developer to the next level of C# mastery.

I am looking for a book that can help me make that transition. Dealing with issues like theory on having more robust C# code when connecting to external systems etc. Error logging techniques, and generally better memory usage, and re factoring.

Anyone know of a good book, that's worth the read?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jon Skeet's "C# in Depth" is pretty good: [http://www.amazon.com/C-Depth-Jon-Skeet/dp/1933988363/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1259183768&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988363)

Comment: While C# in Depth will improve your coding and understanding, I'm not sure it addresses many of the issues raised in the question. And due to peer-reviews, I've read it quite a few times...

Comment: Agreed. It doesn't even *try* to talk about this sort of thing.

Comment: Anyone know if its possible to buy an e-book copy, don't really want to wait for print version p&p

Comment: @JL: Absolutely. I recommend you buy the second edition, which is in early access preview. You'll get the first edition ebook for free, and regular updates to the second edition as I write and edit it. Get it from http://manning.com/skeet2

Answer (score 5):

[Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321245660) and [More Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321485890) by Bill Wagner come highly recommended

Comment: I've always wondered: Is that `(More Effective) C#`, or `More (Effective C#)`?

Comment: I'd be inclined to say the latter, given the first book is Effective C#

Comment: I found Effective C# disappointing, with a lot of self-evident advice and some highly arguable recommendations. It did not made me want to check out the sequel.

Comment: I liked Effective C# - but my situation was somewhat different from JL's.  I'm an experienced developer, but relatively new to .Net and C#.

Comment: Effective C++ is a wonderful book.  I'd be afraid that somebody copying the title like that would fail to live up to the original.

Answer (score 3):

If you're a very good C# dev, you should perhaps look beyond a certain language and technology and try: Domain Driven Design. It's a great book and promotes ideas that help writing great software.

Comment: interesting point, will look into this.

Answer (score 3):

The best book I have found for C# internals is [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632) by Jeffrey Richter.

Answer (score 0):

Not a C# book per se, but [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) (Gamma et al) might be a good introduction to more abstract, architectural concepts.